# I can not see values in my dropdown

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable, devexpress

I am using `DataSet`/`DataTable` adapters to retrieve data from my database.

Now I need a list of suppliers to my dropdown but unfortunately it is empty all the time, even if I catch with a breakpoint that there are some results.

Here is my code:

```
Dim riLookup As New RepositoryItemLookUpEdit()
 riLookup.NullText = String.Empty

 riLookup.DataSource = DataTableDobTableAdapter.FillDob(Me.DsOrders.DataTableDob)
 riLookup.ValueMember = "ID"
 riLookup.DisplayMember = "TITLE"
 riLookup.BestFitMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup
 GridView1.Columns("Code").ColumnEdit = riLookup
```

What I see when I am debugging:

[image]

First of all I dont know why is integer writter there,
and when I continue with debugging and apps run there are empty values:

[image]

**EDIT:**[image]

I never before worked with v.b and devexpress controles so all of this is very confusing to me..

@ ED when I rightclick on my method and choose "Go To Definition" I am seeing this:

```
Public Overloads Overridable Function FillDob(ByVal dataTable As dsOrders.DataTableDobDataTable) As Integer
            Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(0)
            If (Me.ClearBeforeFill = true) Then
                dataTable.Clear
            End If
            Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
            Return returnValue
        End Function
```

I can see there  `As Integer` but why is that if I can see on data preview my real columns from database and neither of them is Integer.. I am really confused here :/

Comment: Find out what `DataTableDobTableAdapter.FillDob(Me.DsOrders.DataTableDob)` returns. That's what you're assigning to DataSource. Looks like it might return an integer.

Comment: In the DataTableDob DataTable, do you have a DataColumn that is named "TITLE" (all capital letters)? Or is it perhaps "Title" or "title". Character-casing can matter with some of the DevExpress controls. Have you tried adding a LookUpColumnInfo to the RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.Columns property (see: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdit_Columnstopic)?

Comment: @EdPlunkett mate, please check for edit, it is acctually returning rows from my SUPPLIERS table, and the rows are : ID, TITLE, Code.

Comment: @Brendon Column names are allright I saw it in data preview

Comment: @Roxy'Pro You're telling me you right-clicked on `DataTableDobTableAdapter.FillDob()`, selected "Go To Definition", and the declared return type was a collection of some kind of data row object?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Just out of idle curiosity, do you find the rows in `DsOrders.DataTableDob` after the adapter fills it and returns the count?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Check for edite mate

Comment: The `FillDob` adapter method fills the table and returns the count. Don't assign an integer to DataSource. Assign the filled table to DataSource. Can you see `Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)` in that code? It's filling the data table there. So use the filled datatable.

Comment: @EdPlunkett And how could I do that ? "assign the filled table to DataSource" I've never before worked with DataTable so please post this as answer and I will accept it and vote it up because looks like that's it what was causing the issue.

Comment: You're assigning something to DataSource now. See if you can find the code where you assign something to DataSource. Now think real hard about how you might assign something different to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fill method on the adapter fills the DataTable and returns the count of rows that it filled the DataTable with. It's right there in the code you showed me for the fill method:

```
        Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
        Return returnValue
```

`Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)`. Then the DataTable has rows in it.

The rows are in the DataTable. Use the DataTable as the data source.

```
Dim riLookup As New RepositoryItemLookUpEdit()
    riLookup.NullText = String.Empty

    DataTableDobTableAdapter.FillDob(Me.DsOrders.DataTableDob)

    riLookup.DataSource = Me.DsOrders.DataTableDob

    riLookup.ValueMember = "ID"
    riLookup.DisplayMember = "TITLE"
    riLookup.BestFitMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup
    GridView1.Columns("Code").ColumnEdit = riLookup
```

Comment: I am still wondering why does that returned the count of rows, I am trying to figure it out

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Because that's the way they wrote it. It doesn't really need to return anything. It gives you the rows by filling the table you give it as a parameter. It could just as easily not have any return value at all.

Comment: I am seriously thinking about involving EF into this project so I might handle my data by using stored procedures and real tables and objects. Thanks one more time